# Knowing that $z$ students failed, how many men failed the exam, out of 452 students? (A $1892$ coll. alg. problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, word-problem

In Tibbets' *College Requirements In Algebra*, at Ginn&Compagny,  $1892$ I find the following *sight problem* ( assuming this expression means that the problem can be solved by simple inspection) :

> Of 452 students who tried the examination last June, $x$ were men,
> the rest were women. In all, $z$ students failed. How many of the
> failures were men?

The only information I can derive from what precedes is that :

number of women : $492-x$.

My question : is this problem simply *solvable*?

[image]

Comment: It's 452, not 492.

Comment: No, it is not solvable in the modern sense. However, maybe by the sexist "logic" back then, they expected you either to conclude that only women were failures, so the answer = 0 or that women simply wouldn't be admitted, so x = 452 and answer = z.

Comment: You must be right ... I hoped for some extraordinary algebraic trick...

Comment: @Deepak I looked at Q4 and thought "how could this be college level algebra? This should be taught in Primary 1 already!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four variables – combinations of pass/fail and male/female – but only three equations corresponding to the quantities $452,x,z$, so the problem *per se* is not solvable.

However, in 1892 college attendance was mostly reserved to men in the United States, so there may have been the implicit assumption that there are no women and the answer would simply be $z$.

Comment: I had actually abstained from posting a facetious comment like your last line, but after I saw your answer, I figured what the heck.

Comment: Or perhaps they were just asking for the experimental number of men (zx/452)